# Segmented controller not hiding items on launch

Tags: iphone, ios, controller

I have a segmented controller that I have programed and it works and all, but there is one problem. When the app first launches it has all of the items (even the ones I have programmed to be hidden). See pictures below.

When I first run my app, it looks like this.

[image: When I first run my app, it looks like this.]

I click the segmented controller to switch to the other view and this happens

[image]

Then I click back to the original and they are hidden they way they are supposed to be.

[image]

**How do I get it so that when I launch the app it appears like the last two pictures instead of some of all of it being un-hidden?**

Comment: Where are you hiding the elements? awakeFromNib? viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the "A" in [A setHidden:YES] is not nil

Comment: what do you mean? i used dot formation (shoppingList.hidden = YES;)

Comment: Then make sure the shoppingList is not nil

Comment: wouldn't our lives be easier if messages to nil...oh nevermind.